# how to use callback at C++?

Tags: c++, callback

i only know lua

```
function yolo(callback)
    if callback then
        callback()
    end
end

function init()
    yolo(function()
        Print("Hello World?")
    end)
end
```

i hope to use this at C++

can someone help me?

```
void Delay(int Delay) {
    atomic<bool> abort(false);
    thread delay([&abort](int delay) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(delay));

        callback();

        abort = true;
    }, std::ref(Delay));

    delay.join();
}

int main()
{
    Delay(300, function()
        cout << "Hello, World!";
    end);
}
```

it's just example what i hope,

somebody help me?

i just want to use delay with variable callback

this is what i tried

```
void HelloWorld(void(*callback) ()) {
        callback();
}

int main()
{
    void a()
    {
        cout << "Hello World?!";
    }
    HelloWorld(a);
}
```

Comment: You can't define functions inside another function. That aside, the code is mostly right, some typo aside. https://wandbox.org/permlink/By1ec99eD7CElcwo

Comment: @BaummitAugen I think you can define a lambda expression in a function or std::function. That would be a way to declare a function in a function in C++.

Comment: Please improve your question with correct case shift. The current style is impolite!

Comment: @MCH I was talking about functions as in function types. If you include any callable, lambdas and other local class types do indeed work as "function definition" in a broader sense of the term.

Answer (score 3):

C++11 introduced `std::function` which is a good way of dealing with function pointers and implement your callback mechanic.

Something like this would work:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void HelloWorld(std::function<void(void)> fn) {
        fn();
}

void callbackFunction() {
    std::cout << "Callback function" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    HelloWorld([]() { std::cout << "Lambda callback" ; });
    HelloWorld(callbackFunction);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void HelloWorld(void(*callback) ()) {
    callback();
}

int main()
{
    auto x = []() {
        std::cout << "Hello World?!";
    };
    HelloWorld(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for function pointer invocation.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void HelloWorld(void(*callback) ()) {
        callback();
}
void a()
    {
        cout << "Hello World?!";
    }
int main()
{
    HelloWorld(a);
}
```

for passing arguments.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void HelloWorld(void(*callback) (int)) {
        callback(9);
}
void a(int a)
    {
        cout << "Hello World?! value:"<<a;
    }
int main()
{
    HelloWorld(a);
}
```